# No Presto metadata available for base Error downloading packages:

Tags: linux, perl, centos7

Whenever I am trying to download

perl-ExtUtils-ParseXS-3.18-2.el7 RPM for noarch (or)

```
 yum install CPAN […]
```

Or

```
 yum install perl-ExtUtils-Embed...
```

Or any other package in CentOS.

It is seeing for dependencies then asking for confirmation (y) to download 
I am getting the below error:

```
No Presto metadata available for base
```

And trying for the mirror and getting the below message:

```
Error Downloading Packages.
```

Comment: Try disabling presto with _yum --disableplugin=presto_.  If that doesn't help then try erasing presto with _yum erase yum-presto_.  See if that helps.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try running:

```
sudo yum clean all
```

Comment: worked like a charm. I had jenkins installed already and after removing it, could it install it again with deltarpm and Presto issues. With just clean all, able to reinstall jenkins. thanks..

Comment: this solution didnt work for me for  php72-php-fpm @remi .

Answer (score 1):

Yum is designed to support DeltaRPM (Presto), however we currently do not use this feature in the Red Hat Repositories.

Disable the warning by editing /etc/yum.conf and add or change the following:

`deltarpm=0`

From: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3141231

Answer (score 0):

Also, check if the URL in the repo is a valid one and is still working.

In OL
/etc/yum.repos.d/[your-repo-name].repo